# How to redefine both fancy and fancyplain styles?

Tags: fancyhdr

I am using the `fancyhdr` package in order to customise the headers and footers of my document.

If I want to center the page number in the footer of all page I use

```
\fancyfoot[C]\thepage
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
```

Moreover if I want to display something in the header of non-title pages I can use

```
\fancyfoot[R]{2021}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

How to combine both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\pagestyle{fancyplain}` is outdated.
You should redefine the `plain` pagestyle:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{2021}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyfoot[R]{} % On `plain' pages no right footer field.
}
```